# Use functions as useEffect dependencies -> "dependency 'props' missing"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

My intention is to use a function (received by a parent component, created with `useCallback`) as dependency in `useEffect` and only trigger that effect if the function changes.

Consider the following simple component:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyState(props.calculate(1));
  }, [props.calculate]) 

  return <h1>{myState}</h1>;
}
```

It receives a function `calculate` in props and computes `myState` from it. However I get the linting error:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.
```

I don't understand why `props.calculate` is not sufficient as a dependency and we need `props`. I don't want to use `props` because then the effect would retrigger on every render, even if `calculate` did not change. (Assume `calculate` has been created using `useCallback` in parent).

The following version does not get any linting errors:

```
function MyComponentVersion2(props) {
  const { calculate } = props;
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyState(calculate(1));
  }, [calculate]) 

  return <h1>{myState}</h1>;
}
```

My questions are:

- Why is the linter not fine with `MyComponent`?
- Are there semantical differences in `MyComponent` compared to `MyComponentVersion2`?

I made a minimal example here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-gauss-ee4xg?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the call `props.calculate(1)` implicitly passes `props` as the `this` value to `calculate`, so technically the result may depend on the entire `props` object (see [this React issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16265#issuecomment-517518539)). For the deconstructed `calculate` call, `this` will be undefined or the global object, so there's no dependency on `props`.

You can see the difference between the two components by replacing `(x) => {return x + 1;}` with `function (x) {console.log(this); return x + 1;}` in the definition of `calculate`.

Comment: Thank you! That was precisely the answer to my problem.